# PHP mail() function not working on QNAP

Tags: html, email, php, nas

I've created a really good online time sheet for my company.

I've started a Linux Apache server on my mac and tested it by accessing `localhost/index.php`.
Once the form is filled out the mail is then received by mail "works 100%"

However once uploaded to the webserver, nothing happens when I click to submit the form. I then created a simple PHP test with the following code:

```
<?php
mail('Myemailadress is entered here','Test mail','The mail function is working!');
echo 'Mail sent!';
?>
```

Even with that simple code nothing happens? Works from my Mac though!

Therefore I'm thinking, that the QNAP 509 pro nas´es web server, doesn't support it or something.

The page and everything is showing up nicely even though it's made with PHP coding.

The whole page runs : HTML / PHP / JavaScript

Comment: Because your mail server is not properly configured..

Comment: why you are using the keyword java???

Comment: Which line of code is hit when the blank page gets returned? [PHP Error Reference: Nothing is seen. The page is empty and white.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12772851/367456)

Comment: You don't even test `mail()`'s return value. Have you enabled error reporting?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure the SMTP or make sure that you even have access to one:
use

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.<whatever>.com");
```

Cheers.

Comment: [Used under Windows only](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp).

Answer (score 0):

**sendmail** must be installed in your server. Try checking for that.

Answer (score 0):

instead of sending from server you can try to send via SMTP server. You can do this by using PEAR Mail Class, Zend Mail Class, PHPMailer or similar.